# Incorrect use of constructor

Tags: solidity, remix, constructor

I cannot get my code to compile under 0.8.18.

I get the error:

```
Warning: Visibility for constructor is ignored. If you want the contract to be non-deployable, making it "abstract" is sufficient.
  --> contracts/Provenance.sol:14:3:
   |
14 |        constructor(bytes32 _UID, bytes mem ... , bytes memory _PhotoHash) public {
   |        ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
```

Here is the offending code snippet:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.18;

    contract Object {
        bytes32 private UID;
        bytes private Desc;
        uint    private ObjectValue;
        uint    private LastPrice;
        uint    private CertificateDate;
        bytes   private DocCID;
        bytes   private PhotoCID;
        bytes   private DocHash;
        bytes   private PhotoHash;

        constructor(bytes32 _UID, bytes memory _Desc, uint _ObjectValue, uint _LastPrice, uint _CertificateDate, bytes memory _DocCID, bytes memory _PhotoCID, bytes memory _DocHash, bytes memory _PhotoHash) public {
            UID             = _UID;
            Desc            = _Desc;
            ObjectValue     = _ObjectValue;
            LastPrice       = _LastPrice;
            CertificateDate = _CertificateDate;
            DocCID          = _DocCID;
            PhotoCID        = _PhotoCID;
            DocHash         = _DocHash;
            PhotoHash       = _PhotoHash;
            }

        function getUID() view public returns (bytes32) {
            return UID;
            }

        function getDesc() view public returns (bytes memory) {
            return Desc;
            }

        function getObjectValue() view public returns (uint) {
            return ObjectValue;
            }

        function getLastPrice() view public returns (uint) {
            return LastPrice;
            }

        function getCertificateDate() view public returns (uint) {
            return CertificateDate;
            }

        function getDocCID() view public returns (bytes memory) {
            return DocCID;
            }

        function getPhotoCID() view public returns (bytes memory) {
            return PhotoCID;
            }

        function getDocHash() view public returns (bytes memory) {
            return DocHash;
            }

        function getPhotoHash() view public returns (bytes memory) {
            return PhotoHash;
            }

        function isDocAuthentic(bytes memory _testDocHash) view public returns (bool) {
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(DocHash))  == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_testDocHash)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
            }

        function isPhotoAuthentic(bytes memory _testPhotoHash) view public returns (bool) {
            if (keccak256(abi.encodePacked(PhotoHash))  == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_testPhotoHash)))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
            } // function isPhotoAuthentic(bytes32 _testPhotoHash)

        function getBalances() public view returns (uint, uint) {
            return (ObjectValue, LastPrice);
            } // function getBalances() public view returns (uint, uint)

    } // Object
```

I last compiled it using pragma solidity ^0.7.6 so I am not surprised, but I don't understand the error...

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove public in constructor().

Comment: Thank-you! I feel rather foolish... :-)